# Refreshing div content (php content) with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i am trying to be able to edit my custom cms blog posts without leaving the page.

The way it works is each post has a edit button which when clicked hides the post text, and displays a ckeditor and also a save button.

All the code works correctly behind the scenes as to say, when saved an ajax call is made to another php page which updates the posts content. Now the issue is i want to on save, show again the text and hide the editor.

I can get this working, but i cant get the div text to update to the new content until the page is refreshed.

So the ajax looks like so:

```
 // ... goes after Validation
    if (check == true) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process/updatepost.php",
    data: $targetForm.serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){

    if (response.databaseSuccess)
       $targetForm.find('.editor').toggle('hide'),
       $targetForm.find('.buildtext').load('http://localhost/buildsanctuary/viewbuild.php?id=134 +bt+'),
       $targetForm.find('.buildtext').toggle('show'), 
       $targetForm.find('.edity').toggle('show'), 
       $targetForm.find('.saveupdatebutton').toggle('hide');
    else
       $ckEditor.after('<div class="error">Something went wrong!</div>');

}
```

and this is how im trying to use a variable in the selector...

```
var bt = $(this).attr(".buildtext");
```

hope this all makes sense?

Craig.

Comment: hoe do you get your Id and where is your variable 'bt' is decleared

Comment: is this page where you retrievd your post from database http://localhost/buildsanctuary/viewbuild.php

Comment: okay i have seen where you declare the 'bt' but how do you generates the post id [134]

Comment: isn't buildtext a class? Why are you using it as an attribute? Or is it also an attribute? I mean because of this: var bt = $(this).attr(".buildtext");

Comment: ignore most of this...

seems to be working but only if there is one post on the page.

Ill have to look into it more as its only actually updating the last post on the page if theres more than one